# What flowering plants are recommended for a roof garden in a climate with hot dry summers?

Tags: plant-recommendations, roof-garden

I live in a hot (now 42 °C to 25°C) and dry (14% relative humidity just right now) city, and I have around 15 hours of sunlight. I wanted to plant some flowers on my roof, where there are no shadows during the day. It also can get subzero (around -10 °C) and 60 to 70% humidity in winters.

What flowers do you recommend for such conditions? For example I have also some [*Aptenia cordifolia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptenia_cordifolia) and they're growing well in similar conditions.

Comment: There's one very important bit of information missing - is the roof load bearing?

Comment: Tomatoes can grow in pots, and produce food for you.

Comment: @Bamboo Hi, I don't know what that is, we have Bituminous waterproofing, and I wanted them not to have deep roots, since I'm going to put them in a shallow pot.

Comment: You need  to check - bitumen waterproofing is no guide, and actually is more likely to mean it isn't weight bearing - pots with wet soil in them are heavy, not to mention your having to get up on the roof to water and maintain plants periodically.

Comment: @Bamboo the roof itself I don't think would have any problem, because it's also holding the cooling system, BTW I was planing to secure the pots on the edges (I don't know technical terms i.e. the short wall surrounding the roof) so I think it wouldn't have any problem with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sedums!  They can be grown in very thin soil like a PICTURE.  They are used in breath taking rooftop live aboard boats as well as vertical on the sides of buildings, walls.  You will be blown away how beautiful, hardy and how they change with the seasons!

Comment: Yes. And maybe some cactus like Prickly Pear and San Pedro.